# Numpy mask array on both sides

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume a numpy array x. How can I do `x[x>value] = max(value1, x[x>value])`?

In words, if element `x[i] > value`, then `x[i] = max(value1, x[i])`.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Using `numpy.maximum` instead of `numpy.max` solved the problem. When I had `numpy.max` I was getting the error message `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array:

```
In [361]: x = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
In [362]: x
Out[362]: array([7, 8, 4, 8, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 9])
```

Identify the values to be replaced:

```
In [363]: mask = x>5
In [364]: mask
Out[364]: 
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,
        True])
In [365]: x[mask]
Out[365]: array([7, 8, 8, 6, 6, 9])
```

The replacement values:

```
In [368]: np.maximum(7, x[mask])
Out[368]: array([7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 9])
```

As long as the both sides have the same number of terms (`shape` actually):

```
In [369]: x[mask] = np.maximum(7, x[mask])
In [370]: x
Out[370]: array([7, 8, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 9])
```

Since this is actually just changing the values between 5 and 7, we could use:

```
In [378]: x = np.array([7, 8, 4, 8, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 9])
In [379]: mask = (x>5) & (x<7)
In [380]: mask
Out[380]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False])
In [381]: x[mask]
Out[381]: array([6, 6])
In [382]: x[mask] = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` and single combined condition:

```
np.where((x>value)&(x<value1), value1, x)
```

or equivalently:

```
x[(x>value) & (x<value1)] = value1
```

Example:

```
x = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
value=5
value1=10
#output:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```